# Read out an XML file and search for a specific word. Then put this word on a page. Code in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, windows

I have to read out an XML file and I have to search for 0GEW903KA. This code must then be on one page. I can't get it to read the XML file. With a .txt, I can already read the code, but it always outputs the entire line and not just the word. Can you help me please.

sheet.info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" sheetInfoVersion="1.0" infoType="SheetInfo">
<uid>10000005-e59b-4723-a941-8d5942ff1673</uid>
<sheetType hasTemporaryMOP="false" regularMOPLocation="">ALS</sheetType>
<revision />
<timestamps>
    <created>2019-08-26 12:27:30</created>
    <lastWrite>2019-08-26 12:27:30</lastWrite>
    <lastAccess>2019-08-26 12:27:30</lastAccess>
</timestamps>
<sheetName />
    <idCode>0GEW903KA</idCode>
    <versionInfo>
        <comment>initial revision</comment>
        <date>2019-08-26 12:27:30</date>
        <increment>0</increment>
        <user>LA2TERMSERV/html_eng1</user>
        <version>1</version>
        <state>Undefined</state>
        <creationToolName>HTML_Editor</creationToolName>
        <creationToolVersion>2.6.0</creationToolVersion>
        <creationToolLibVersion>HTML 2.6.0</creationToolLibVersion>
    </versionInfo>
</configuration>
```

my current mess code
my attempt to read xml files

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('C:/xampp/htdocs/Flutter/Probe/sheet.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// move to the first <product /> node
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'idCode');

// now that we're at the right depth, hop to the next <product/> until the end of the tree
while ($z->name === 'idCode') {
    // either one should work
    //$node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

    // now you can use $node without going insane about parsing
    echo $node;
}
```

Comment: If you were to add your code and sample data you might find it elicits a better response - as it stands nobody can help you as the requirements are so vague as to be meaningless.

Comment: i have changed my question

Comment: nevermind i managed it myself

Comment: Then you can add your own answer and accept it. Currently, you have indicated that you have solved your problem with the answer by ThW below.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not match the XML example (here is not "product" element) and the XML does not look like it would need XMLReader (large xml file).

So with just DOM + Xpath:

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/configuration/idCode)'));
```

Output:

```
string(9) "0GEW903KA"
```

Xpath allows you to fetch nodes and values from DOM using expressions. The expression here is:

- Fetch the "configuration" document element node...
  `/configuration`
- ... fetch the "idCode" child elements ...
  `/configuration/idCode`
- ... cast the first found node to a string
  `string(/configuration/idCode)`

Your example code misses the actual string value read and it is an endless loop because it does not move to the next node. Here is a fixed example with the different possibilities after you navigate to the "idCode"element node:

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
//$reader->open('C:/xampp/htdocs/Flutter/Probe/sheet.xml');
$reader->open('data:text/xml;base64,'.base64_encode($xmlString));

$document = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'idCode');

while ($reader->localName === 'idCode') {
    // expand idCode into prepared document
    $node = $reader->expand($document);
    // importing into SimpleXML is an additional step
    $idCode = simplexml_import_dom($node);
    
    var_dump(
      [
          // direct read without expand into DOM
          'XMLReader::readString' => $reader->readString(),
          // text content of the expanded node
          'DOMNode::$textContent' => $node->textContent,
          // xpath expression using expanded node as context
          'Xpath expression' => $xpath->evaluate('string(.)', $node),
          // cast the imported SimpleXMLElement instance
          'SimpleXMLElement' => (string)$idCode
      ]
    );
    
    // look for a sibling "idCode"
    $reader->next('idCode');
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["XMLReader::readString"]=>
  string(9) "0GEW903KA"
  ["DOMNode::$textContent"]=>
  string(9) "0GEW903KA"
  ["Xpath expression"]=>
  string(9) "0GEW903KA"
  ["SimpleXMLElement"]=>
  string(9) "0GEW903KA"
}
```